# Dual problem to SDP problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, dual-cone

I'm having problem with formulating dual problem to Semidefinite programing problem:
$$\max\;\;tr(X)$$

$$s.t.\;\; \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 A & X \\
X & B
\end{array} \right]\succeq0$$

where A, B are symmetric and positive definite matricies and X is symmetric.

It is known that a general SDP has the following Primar Dual pair:

$$P) \;\; \min \;\; tr(C^TX)$$

$$s.t.\;\; tr(A_{i}^TX)=b_i\;\;i=1,...,m$$
$$X\succeq 0$$

$$D)\;\; \max b^Ty$$

$$s.t.\;\; \sum_{i=1}^{m}A_iy_i + S = C $$
$$S\succeq0$$

however, I cannot find a way, how to reformulate it. Thank You

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried putting your problem into (P) form?  (D) form?  If might help to introduce some notation for the block matrix in your constraint, $Z=[A \; X ; X \; B]$.

Comment: I've started with putting the problem into this form:
$$
min \quad -0.5 tr(CZ)
$$
$$
s.t.: Z \geq 0
$$

Where C = [0 I; I 0] and henece the (D) should be:
$$
max 0
$$
$$
s.t: S = -C \\
S \geq 0
$$ 
therefore the (D) is Inf, but that's not correct.

Comment: You haven't constrained the upper left and lower right blocks of $Z$ to equal $A$ and $B$.  This can be done with a bunch of linear equality constraints.

Comment: You'll also need linear equality constraints to ensure that the $X$ block in $Z$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try.

Comment: You have an LMI so it is most natural to put in (D) form and read off (P) from that.